# Loading certain page elements based on IP address

Tags: javascript, php, html

Couldn't quite find this exact question but I may have missed it. I was wondering whats the best way to load certain page elements based on the IP address of the site the visitor is coming from. In other words I only want to load a certain navigation button if the site visitor came from site X.

We are testing some cross-domain navigation on an e-commerce site and I want to provide a link that will get people back to their shopping cart if they navigate away from it to our main site. But I only want the link to show up if the people came from e-commerce site, hence I want to only load the link element if the referring IP address is a certain one.

I found the below code but I'm kind of a php newb so i don't know if this is the best way, or if there is a better way using javascript.

```
If ($_SERVER[“HTTP_REFERER”] == “ip address X”) 
{
               echo “<a href="http:// etc, etc"><div id=""> Back to shopping cart</div></a>”;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTTP_REFERER contains absolute URL of source page. Not IP address. Just try insert in page <?php echo($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]); ?> and see to output for examples.

Comment: Change the curly quotes `“ip address X”` to standard ones `"ip address X"`. That alone should have thrown you a 500 error. Do the same for the ones in `echo “<a href="http:// etc, etc"><div id=""> Back to shopping cart</div></a>”;`

Comment: @2astalavista that wont help here - the ip address of the client isn't relevant

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER'] cannot really be trusted (see documentation http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). My Question is : Can you modify both the sources in domain 'A' and in domain 'B' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Note that the referer is **NOT** reliable. While in most cases it will show where a user came from, you should not DEPEND on it being accurate. Security/privacy software will tamper with the value or suppress it entirely.

That being said: the referer is just a url, so

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$urlparts = parse_url($url); // decompose url into components

$host = $urlparts['host']; // get the hostname

$ip = gethostbyname($host); // do DNS lookup for hostname->ip

if ($ip == '127.0.0.1') {
   echo "Hey, you must be sitting next to me!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry for the syntax. The code was just something I found and  copied and pasted so I hadn't cleaned it up yet.

Comment: Thanks again. I realize HTTP_REFERER is not really reliable but we have control over any referring pages/domains/etc at this point since this is just for some testing. Marc B's answer worked, thanks for the help and patience.